# Is it possible to devise a Python function that "knows" if it's executed inside an if-then block?

Tags: python, scope, conditional-statements, control-flow

Is there any way to devise a Python function that checks whether it's executed inside an if-then block? Specifically, it would do this:

```
if cond_is_true:
     is_inside_if1 = check_if_inside_if_block()  # evaluate to True

is_inside_if2 = check_if_inside_if_block()  # evaluate to False
```

In this case, is_inside_if1 would be True, and is_inside_if2 would be False. Is this even possible or is there no magic dark enough to do this? I know it's possible for a function that checks the scope in which it is executed, but I don't know if this also applies to if-then blocks.

On an analogous note, is there a way to have a function or object that knows whether it's being called inside the cond_is_true statement?

My use case is that I'm designing a Python package that takes arbitrary neural network models and tries to deduce the computational graph of the model without changing any of the code, and some of this scope-inspection dark magic might end up being necessary for this process to be exhaustive.

Comment: No, its not possible.

Comment: The [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) module provides some tools for navigating the frame stack if you are doing this on the fly.

Comment: Have you looked at the `inspect` module?  You can use that to figure out what line of code you're on (for each frame of the stack).

Comment: Encapsulation goes both ways. The caller doesn't necessarily know what's going on inside the function, and the function doesn't know about the context in which it is called. If the context matters, you communicate it by passing an argument to the function that the function uses to make decisions.